# Add a JavaFX Group a Max Width and Height

Tags: javafx

I have a JavaFX Group with a set of SVGPath's and the problem occurs when i try put a specific size for the Group. The group doesn't response me and put the original size of the file. I try put the group into a AnchorPane and them put a size in the AnchorPane and doesn't work.

```
package es.raulgf.mapfrance2;

import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.shape.SVGPath;

public class MapFrance2 extends AnchorPane {

 public double originalWeight=450;
public double originalHeight=650;

Group map;

public MapFrance2(double height,double width){

    setMaxHeight(height);
    setPrefHeight(height);
    setPrefWidth(width);
    setMaxWidth(width);

    try {
        map=FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("MapFranceEmpty.fxml"));

        map.setScaleX(height/originalHeight);
        map.setScaleY(width/originalWeight);

        getChildren().add(map);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }
```

}

other questions is how can resize my Group of SVGPath's and the SVG draw not exceed the AnchorPane border?

Comment: From the javadoc: *[...] a Group will "auto-size" its managed resizable children to their preferred sizes during the layout pass [...]*. Obviously this seems to be the wrong kind of layout. Furthermore shapes are not resizeable, so you need to work with `scaleX`/`scaleY`...

Comment: When i use the scaleX and scaleY, The group surpass size of the Pane that contain it. How can block the expansion of the group around the size of Pane introduced for me?

Answer (score 0):

Put the group with the SVGPath inside StackPane that will fix your problem.